# OpenCV capturing image with black side bars

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to capture photos and videos using cv2.VideoCapture and cameras with an aspect ratio of 16:9. All image is returned by OpenCV have black sidebars, cropping the image. In my example, instead of returning an image with 1280 x 720 pixels, it returns a 960 x 720 image. The same thing happens with a C920 webcam (1920 x 1080).

What am I doing wrong?

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while True:
    conected, frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('s'):
        video.release()
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Using OpenCV:

[image: Image with black sides]

Using Windows Camera:

[image]

Comment: maybe you should upgrade OpenCV version to 3 latest

Comment: Im using OpenCV 3.4.2

Comment: Maybe your camera isn't capable of 1280x720, not all cameras shoot all resolutions.

Comment: When I use Sarxos library or use Windows Camera application, the image is shown correctly.

Comment: Just for fun, try setting the height first, then the width - I mean swap the order of the two lines setting the height and width.

Comment: I tried to change order, but didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Answer of @luismesas is completely right and worked for me.

But for people being as unskilled as I am you need to save the capture returned by cv2.VideoCapture. It is not a Parameter you can set like cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW), it is a method.

```
camera_index = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Confirmed on Webcam device HD PRO WEBCAM C920.

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact issue with a Logitech wide angle in windows camera and I was wondering about a driver problem.

So I solved it using the DirectShow driver instead of the native driver using this:

```
cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

If you have more than one camera add the index to that value like this

```
cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW + camera_index)
```

It will accept the desired resolution by applying the right aspect ratio without having the sidebars.

Comment: an alternative is to do: cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

Comment: When I try the two-argument-version, I get `TypeError: VideoCapture() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue too, but only on Windows 10, OpenCV 3.4 and Python 3.7.
I get the full resolution without the black side bars on a Mac OS.

I used [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/CameraIntro.html) to capture the webcam input and got the full resolution of 1920x1080 on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Just resize the received frame:

```
   cv::Mat dst;
   cv:resize(frame,dst,cv::Size(1280,720));
   cv::imshow("Video",dst);
```

Check it!

Comment: That will just distort the image to fill the size, but it still won't capture the information in the wider field of view.